# What is the best way to configure Kafka topics via PHP

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I want to programmatically configure Kafka topics based on some configuration in xml, yaml or any other format (that is not important) using PHP script.

What is the best way to do that? The only way I came up with is to call kafka binary from PHP script

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name my-topic --alter --add-config max.message.bytes=128000
```

Is it the best approach available or is there any other better one?

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/quipo/kafka-php ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. What exact feature of that library do mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for create topic via php

```
$path='/opt/Kafka/kafka_2.12-1.0.0/';<br/>
$command_topic=$path."bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic NewtopicName";<br/>
$output_topic=shell_exec($command_topic);
```

Comment: That is exactly the only solution the OP came up with himself -- "The only way I came up with is to call kafka binary from PHP script" -- so this is not really an answer.

Comment: @TomRegner but they want to create topic via php so thats the technique